# Aligning the label in d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Following is the data file : myStData.csv

```
xindex,mylabel
40,23
41,13
42,12
43,21
44,40
45,50
```

Following is my code snippet, and currently, the label is shown at "start" (text-anchor is set to start). It is placed at the **start** value of my csv file. But, I want the label to be placed at the **end** value. 
I tried replacing the start text anchor to be end, but it didn't work in my case. Any  help in this is highly appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body { font: 13px Helvetica;}

path { 
 stroke: steelblue;
 stroke-width: 2;
 fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: grey;
 stroke-width: 1;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.legend {
 font-size: 16px;
 text-anchor: start;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
 width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
 .orient("bottom").ticks(14);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
 .orient("left").ticks(5);
  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return x(d.xindex); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d.mylabel); });
 
  
var chart1 = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + (margin.right * 2))
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + (margin.bottom * 2)) 
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
// Get the data
d3.csv("myStData.csv", function(error, data) {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.xindex = +d.xindex;
  d.mylabel = +d.mylabel;
 });

 // Scale the range of the data
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.xindex; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.mylabel; })]);

 chart1.append("path")  // Add the valueline path.
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));


 chart1.append("g")   // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 chart1.append("g")   // Add the Y Axis
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
 chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width+3) + "," + y(data[0].mylabel) + ")")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class","legend")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .text("MyLabel");

 // Add the text label for the Y axis
 chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Y-Axis Label");

 // Add the text label for the x axis
 chart1.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + (margin.bottom * 1.5)) + ")")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("X-Axis Label");
});
```

Comment: which of the labels you want to go to the end, I see you use text-anchor is styles as well as in each time you append the text ... ?

Comment: @Alex_B : I want 'MyLabel' , the label which is displayed across the line to be at the end position

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution. Simple, as it was!
So, to re-iterate, what I wanted to achieve was to move the location of the 'MyLabel' label to the position where the line ends. Here's how it needs to be done:

```
chart1.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width+3) + "," + y(data[0].mylabel) + ")")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("class","legend")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .text("MyLabel");
```

This states that the y-axis position of the label needs to be at data[0] element's y value. We simply need to replace, data[0] by data[data.length-1] so that the y- value of the last data element is taken into consideration for positioning the label.

```
chart1.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width+3) + "," + y(data[data.length-1].mylabel) + ")")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("class","legend")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .text("MyLabel");
```